What is the relative performance trade off between having covered queries vs. index size?
I inherited a SQL Server table with a field that is a very large JSON blob (NVARCHAR(MAX)). The average size of this field is ~8k. The architect wants us to include all fields in the indexes so that we have covered queries. This field is included in the indexes because it is needed for almost every query we perform. This massively bloats the indexes. The table contains approximately 5 million records. What is going to be worse, the performance hit from the extra lookup, or the performance issues resulting from the massively bloated indexes?

What Is the purpose of the queries? Extracting attributes from JSON or get whole JSON string to supply front? Could you post a sample SQL you most used? Is the JSON field frequently updated or deleted? @DavidMorgan

Your question is not complete.Definetly performance issues resulting from the massively bloated indexes?Since JSON blob (NVARCHAR(MAX)) is not part of index rather it is INCLUDED so this column is not culprit.so you need to share index script along with their data type

rookie mistake
You're thinking about this all wrong. You're arguing with the ~architect~ and this will only lead to stupid finger-pointing situations (at you) when their precious application has performance problems at some future point. They will be loud and they will told-you-so on emails with your boss copied in.
One could point and giggle at an ~architect~ that sticks a JSON blob in a relational database rather than parsing it out into proper columns, or storing the BLOB in a separate table with a foreign key to the main table it relates to, of course, and you're free to do so privately. Lives are not likely at stake here.
You're far better off giving them what they want up front. That way, when you run into performance problems, your ~architect~ can't stand around blaming you for not creating the indexes they wanted. They fully own the problems, and you can (when evidence allows) show where their requested indexes are involved with them.
So yeah, for an OLTP application that will only ever retrieve a small number of rows, it's probably stupid overkill to include every column in the table in your nonclustered indexes. That's not what they're intended for in most scenarios, but things may get a bit grey-area when reporting queries come into play.
Sometimes you have to let people screw up. That's the only way they learn. Most people only ever have bird ideas.

What’s reality? I don’t know. When my bird was looking at my computer
monitor I thought, ‘That bird has no idea what he’s looking at.’ And
yet what does the bird do? Does he panic? No, he can’t really panic,
he just does the best he can. Is he able to live in a world where he’s
so ignorant? Well, he doesn’t really have a choice. The bird is okay
even though he doesn’t understand the world. You’re that bird looking
at the monitor, and you’re thinking to yourself, ‘I can figure this
out.’ Maybe you have some bird ideas. Maybe that’s the best you can
do.


That was my position 2 years ago when I first pointed it out, but we did nothing about the indexes. Now we are seeing performance issues. The JSON blob is a necessary evil as the schema are too complex and varied to normalize with a reasonable development effort, but the indexes we can do something about. The told-you-so emails with the director cc'd have already started flying blaming the selecting of all fields causing the query not to be "covered".  All fields are in the index, including a computed field that is almost as big as the JSON blob.Time to break out SQL Profiler and compare.

If you "include all columns in the index" then you're creating a copy of the table that's just sorted a bit differently. If your query is scanning the table/index then it will take the same time with no performance increase. All you've done is introduced additional overhead with index maintenance.
If your queries perform SEEKs on key columns then leave the blob columns in the main table, they will then be retrieved via a KEY or RID lookup.

One key factor would be what the workload on the table consists of.
If it contains mainly static or rarely updated data where selects make up most of the workload then the indexes should not require a great deal of maintenance, and the performance increase from not having to do a lookup on the table could well be worth it.
If it's a frequently modified table on the other hand, with a lot of writes through inserts/updates/deletes, then the additional I/O involved in keeping the indexes up to date may offset the benefit. Also any required defrags/ rebuilds of the index will obviously take longer if they contain large blob columns.
